# Print x values on axis of a graph

Tags: javascript, php

Can some help me with this problem? Now it prints every X value on the x axis. Is it possible to make the loop that it prints every 5th value of the axis and the other for values " "?

Something like "0", " ", " ", " ", " ", "5", " "....

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('lux').getContext('2d');
var lux = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [
            <?php  
            for ($x = 0; $x < (count($data) - 1); $x++) {
                echo $x . ' , ';
            }
            ?>
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: you could replace $x++ with $x+5 in your for loop so it increments by 5's rather than by 1's

Comment: or make use of modulus operator `%` and add a condition `if (($x%5) == 0) echo $x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mod operator ([`%`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)) is a great way to determine if you're on every fifth element or not. I generally try to avoid echoing stuff in `for` loops, especially when outputting into Javascript. I would probably approach this in two chunks: prep the data, then use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to echo out the desired values:

You'll notice [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is used here instead of a loop, once again, just to make things easier to reason about and to provide a variable to reference.

```
<?php

$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

$result = array_map(function ($x, $index) {
    return $index % 5 === 0 ? $x : '';
}, $arr, array_keys($arr));

?>

var ctx = document.getElementById('lux').getContext('2d');
var lux = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>,
                // Outputs: ["a","","","","","f","","","",""]
    }
}
```

You can run the example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01d213a6681368377bb29feb9fa9dd8c9c799921).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php  
    for ($x = 0; $x < (count($data) - 1); $x++) {
       if($x % 5  == 0){
         echo $x; //5th element
       }else{
         echo "''"; //prints empty for other than 5th element
       }
       echo ', '; //prints ',' for every element
    }
?>
```